# Print variable in html page with Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, variables

I have a variable in my ***app.js*** and I want to print it in my HTML page without erease the other text of the page.

Example :

```
var test = 'hello';
```

Here I just want to print `hello` in my ***index.ejs*** page.

Comment: You need to send down and object containing the value {test: "hello"} and then inside the view you can do {{test}} and it'll print the value

Comment: How can i ''send down an object containing the value {test: "hello"}''

Comment: If you can provide the code you have so far, we'll be able to provide a bit more help. If you're using Node.js with Express, then you can use; `res.render("index", {text: "hello"});`

Comment: .I have a page **app.js** with a var and a page **index.ejs** with HTML code. I just want to print the var.

Comment: Ok I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

`var test = 'hello';`
is a variable that you declared it in the app.js. You can print it through the console as `console.log(test)` If you want to print it in your html template, it has to be an object. `{test: 'hello'}` can be printed as `{{test}}` in your ejs html template.Take a look at the documentation of [ejs template engine.](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)